# How to get all result on query before found user_id

Tags: mysql

so if I have a database like this

`SELECT * FROM PRIORITY ORDER BY priority_number ASC`

```
id | user_id | priority_number
------------------------------
1  |    1    |       4         
2  |    5    |       5         
3  |    2    |       6         
4  |    3    |       7         
5  |    6    |       8         
6  |    8    |       9         
7  |    7    |       10         
8  |    10   |       12         
9  |    9    |       13         
10 |    12   |       14         
11 |    13   |       15         
12 |    11   |       16
```

then when I search the `user_id = 7` then I will get the first of the `user_id`

```
id | user_id | priority_number
------------------------------
1  |    1    |       4         
2  |    5    |       5         
3  |    2    |       6         
4  |    3    |       7         
5  |    6    |       8         
6  |    8    |       9         
7  |    7    |       10
```

what I've tried so far.

`SELECT * FROM PRIORITY WHERE priority_number <= 10 ORDER BY priority_number ASC` but I only have `user_id` given

Comment: So you want to get all users, ordered by `priority_number`, that have a `user_id` less than or equal to 7 (or any other value specified as parameter)?

Comment: I want to get all query before the found user_id

Comment: Just use a subquery and a `<=`, i.e. `SELECT * FROM PRIORITY WHERE priority_number <= (SELECT priority_number FROM PRIORITY WHERE user_id = ?)`

Answer (score 0):

In this case it'll be something like that:
`SELECT * FROM PRIORITY WHERE priority_number <= (SELECT priority_number FROM PRIORITY WHERE user_id = 7) ORDER BY priority_number ASC`